# Accuracy on two-layer neural network is not improving

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I am quite new to tensorflow and am making my first two-layer neural network. I am utilizing the heart disease dataset from UCI.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

RANDOM_SEED = 41
tf.set_random_seed(RANDOM_SEED)

def init_weights(shape):
    """ Weight initialization """
    weights = tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(weights)

def forwardprop(X, w_1, w_2, w_3):
    h_1   = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, w_1))
    h_2   = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h_1, w_2))
    yhat = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h_2, w_3))
    return yhat

def get_heart_data():   
    disease = pd.read_csv('../data/disease.csv')

    disease.replace(to_replace="?", value = "u", inplace = True)
    disease = pd.get_dummies(disease, columns=['ca', 'thal', 'fbs', 'exang', 'slop', 'sex', 'cp'], drop_first=True)

    all_X = disease.drop(['pred_attribute'],1)
    all_y = disease['pred_attribute']
    all_y = pd.get_dummies(all_y, columns=['pred_attribute'], drop_first=False)
    return train_test_split(all_X, all_y, test_size=0.3, random_state=RANDOM_SEED)

def main():
    train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = get_heart_data()

    # Layer's sizes
    x_size = 21
    h_1_size = 154 
    h_2_size = 79  
    y_size = 5

    # Symbols
    X = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, x_size])
    y = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, y_size])

    # Weight initializations
    w_1 = init_weights((x_size, h_1_size))
    w_2 = init_weights((h_1_size, h_2_size))
    w_3 = init_weights((h_2_size, y_size))

    # Forward propagation
    logits   = forwardprop(X, w_1, w_2, w_3)

    # Backward propagation
    cost    = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits))
    updates = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

    # Run SGD
    sess = tf.Session()
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)


    for epoch in range(100):
        # Train with each example
        for i in range(len(train_X)):

            sess.run(updates, feed_dict={X: train_X, y: train_y })

        pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)  # Apply softmax to logits
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
        training_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: train_X, y: train_y})
        testing_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: test_X, y: test_y})
        print("Epoch = %d, train accuracy = %.2f%%, test accuracy = %.2f%%"
          % (epoch + 1, 100 * training_accuracy, 100. * testing_accuracy))

    sess.close()

main()
```

I thought that I had set everything up correctly, however when I run the program, it just repeatedly gives me the same accuracy over and over again.

```
Epoch = 1, train accuracy = 55.19%, test accuracy = 51.65%
Epoch = 2, train accuracy = 55.19%, test accuracy = 51.65%
Epoch = 3, train accuracy = 55.19%, test accuracy = 51.65%
Epoch = 4, train accuracy = 55.19%, test accuracy = 51.65%
Epoch = 5, train accuracy = 55.19%, test accuracy = 51.65%
Epoch = 6, train accuracy = 55.19%, test accuracy = 51.65%
Epoch = 7, train accuracy = 55.19%, test accuracy = 51.65%
Epoch = 8, train accuracy = 55.19%, test accuracy = 51.65%
Epoch = 9, train accuracy = 55.19%, test accuracy = 51.65%
Epoch = 10, train accuracy = 55.19%, test accuracy = 51.65%
```

This continues through epoch 100. I have tried multiplying by 100000 in order to see whether it was just changing very slightly, but it stays the same each time. I don't know whether it is my network or my accuracy function or something else.
Your help is much appreciated,
- Matt

Comment: I don't know if this will help with the problem, but the way you are building your network is a problem. Remove the sigmoid nonlinearity from the last layer. The softmax needs logits to work properly. If you push it through a sigmoid, it can't work as well as it should.
`
def forwardprop(X, w_1, w_2, w_3):
    h_1   = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, w_1))
    h_2   = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h_1, w_2))
    yhat = tf.matmul(h_2, w_3)
    return yhat
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test and training sets stay the same at each epoch, so why would you expect a different result?

I think that what you want is to start at epoch 1 with only a few samples, and add more through the epochs:

```
n_epoch = 100
# Assuming of course that you have more than n_epoch samples in each of your sets
trainSamplesByEpoch = int(len(train_X) / n_epoch)      
for epoch in range(1,100):
    train_X_current = train_X[0:epoch*trainSamplesByEpoch] 
    train_y_current = train_y[0:epoch*trainSamplesByEpoch] 
    # Train your network with train_X_current, train_y_current 
    # Compute the train accuracy with train_X_current, train_y_current  
    # Compute the test accuracy with test_X, test_y
```

Epochs are used this way in order to know how many samples are roughly enough to get to the desired performance. Using all your samples may result in an overfitting model.

Comment: By saying "Do your processing with train_X_current and test_X_current" do you mean in the accuracy calculations or the training of the network. Also, you say that my training set stays at the same epoch so the accuracy should remain the same, but I was under the impression that the accuracy would change as the weights were adjusted through backpropagation. I want accuracy to be calculated for every epoch.

Comment: @MatthewCasey I corrected and completed my code, and added the way you should train and compute. Backpropagation is a one-run algorithm, running it multiple times with the same initial conditions will lead to the same result.

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is the way you're building your network.
You are using nonlinearities everywhere, even your output layer.

The loss you're using, `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` requires that the logits be a linear function. So here is the way you should build your network:

```
def forwardprop(X, w_1, w_2, w_3):
h_1   = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, w_1))
h_2   = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h_1, w_2))
yhat = tf.matmul(h_2, w_3)
return yhat
```

The way you have structured your code is also going to cause you problems when you move on to more complex networks.
You shouldn't think of `forwardprop()` and `backprop()`. When writing tensorflow code, think of it as specifying a graph, and the computations necessary. Take a look at [tensorflow tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers), for a gold standard on how to structure your code.